# How to configure kubectl from another pc?Namespaces are empty

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubectl

I have successfully setup the kubectl cli on my laptop to connect to my azure cluster.
If I make, for example:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

I get my namespaces and I can see my resources by navigating to the current namespace.
Now I need to replicate this setup on another laptop of mine and I made the following:

```
az login <--login to azure
az aks install-cli <--install of kubectl
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myCluster <--linking kubectl to my cluster
```

Problem is that, if I make get-contexts again I only get the default namespace. And, of course, that namespace is empty as I put my deployment in another one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I'm not sure what the actual question is. if your resources are in different namespace, you can query those namespaces like you normally would:

```
kubectl get pods -n othernamespace
kubectl edit deployment xxx -n othernamespace
```

you can set the default namespace for the context like so:

```
kubectl set-context xxx --namespace othernamespace
```